# What does the : Operator mean in C++ inheritance?

Tags: c++

I have been reading up on inheritance in C++ and noticed that

```
class Car: public Vehicle {
  public:
    string model = "Mustang";
};
```

You used a ":" operator before the defining the child class, however I couldn't find what this means.

Is it just something we should know to use but not how it works or what it does?

Comment: Continue reading the book. It will explain that a bit later.

Comment: @s.m don't assume that. That's the sorta thing books and tutorials  gloss over. it's a syntax choice by the designers of the language. Why they did it could be anything. C# uses it as well for similar uses. It's likely a context switching trigger for the compiler, to tell it to get ready to start or continue an inheritance chain. It's probably required or else it won't compile the code.

Comment: The colon after `Car` means that you are defining inheritance. That is why you use a colon (not an operator) when defining inheritance. What more is there to know? This is sort of like asking what does the double-quote character mean when defining a string literal such as `"string"` -- defining a string is what that character means in that context.

Comment: @JaMiT I think it's just because I have come from Java where they use the specific keyword "extends" which makes more sense, but yeah I've figure it out to just be a language design choice.

Comment: @RichardBarker: "context switching trigger" is a bit rich. For the parser, it means that the tokens between `:` and `{` are a list of base classes. The compiler then knows to do name lookup, figure out the virtual base classes, include space for the base class subobject, inherit members, etcetera.

Comment: Hypertechincal point: `:` here is not an operator; it's a punctuator.

Comment: @msalters sure, but not entirely inaccurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single colon could also signify class inheritance, if the class declaration is followed by `:` and a class name, it means the class derives from the class behind the single colon.

```
class InheritedClass : public BaseClass.
```